# How to join data.frames based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame that looks like this:

```
d1 <- data.frame(h1 = c("foo","foo","bar","bar"), h2= c("a","b","c","d"), h3=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"))
```

Which prints:

```
   h1 h2 h3
1 foo  a x1
2 foo  b x2
3 bar  c x3
4 bar  d x4
```

And

```
 d2 <- data.frame(t1= c("a","b","c","d"), t2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"),val=(rnorm(4)))
```

Which produces:

```
   t1 t2      val
1  a x1 -1.183606
2  b x2 -1.358457
3  c x3 -1.512671
4  d x4 -1.253105
# surely the val columns will differ since we use rnorm()
```

What I want to do is to combine d1 and d2 based on h2-h3 in d1 and t1-t2 column in d2,
resulting in

```
foo  a x1 -1.183606
foo  b x2 -1.358457
bar  c x3 -1.512671
bar  d x4 -1.253105
```

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge works with multiple keys, and can use different column names for each side.  For the `by` specifications, `x` is the first data frame, `y` is the second:

```
merge(d1, d2, by.x=c('h2', 'h3'), by.y=c('t1', 't2'))
##   h2 h3  h1         val
## 1  a x1 foo -0.04356036
## 2  b x2 foo  0.56975774
## 3  c x3 bar  0.03251157
## 4  d x4 bar -0.67823770
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick -- you create a single key out of the column pairs for each data frame and then merge on that key:

```
d1$key = paste(d1$h2, d1$h3)
d2$key = paste(d2$t1, d2$t2)
merged = merge(d1, d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using `data tables`.

Joins are exceptionally efficient with data tables. Even with these tiny datasets, a data table join is about twice as fast, although you wouldn't notice it. With larger datasets the difference is enormous.

```
# data frames with 200,000 rows, same structure as OP's example
df1 <- data.frame(h1=rep(c("foo","foo","bar","bar"),each=50000),
                  h2=rep(letters[1:20],1e4),
                  h3=rep(1:1e4,each=20))
df2 <- data.frame(t1=rep(letters[1:20],1e4),
                  t2=rep(1:1e4,each=20),
                  val=rnorm(2e5))
# time the merge (~8.4 sec)
system.time(df.result <-merge(df1, df2, by.x=c('h2', 'h3'), by.y=c('t1', 't2')))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  8.41    0.02    8.42 

# convert to data tables and set keys
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key="h2,h3")
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key="t1,t2")
# time the join (~0.2 sec)
system.time(dt.result <- dt1[dt2])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.19    0.00    0.18
```

Bottom line: data table joins are > 40 times faster on large datasets.